# line break/image shift in video from webcam

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player

when I move with my webcam quickly, I see these artefacts/image breaks/shifts. I am using vlc v4l2 with /dev/video0 via vlc command line to preview live webcam video. Please, What should I set please to prevent these artefacts?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Peanut Gallery, but I would try upping the number of frames per second the webcam is capturing. It seems likely they are not being captured enough for the changes in the movement of the camera.

Comment: Welcome and good luck. =)